# What type of faucet is this?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, faucet

I cannot for the life of me figure out what kind of faucet this is. I need to replace the stems as they are leaking but without knowing the brand I am stumped!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any pictures from other angles? (FYI -- took me to figure out the picture was from underneath looking up, for anyone else baffled at first). The knob(s) would be good to see as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's an *installed* faucet as far as I can make out.  To replace the stems it is not necessary to know the mfr and model (though might be helpful), instead just bring them in to a plumbing store (ideally) or Home Depot.

I once brought my broken version of this part:

[image]

in to a plumbing store.  Without out my saying a word, the counterhelp simply looked at it, said 'ok', walked back into the stock shelves and came back with the replacement kit.

Comment: Hi Everyone, here is a better angle. Sorry for the confusing photo http://i.imgur.com/UezOmTy.jpg

Comment: thanks. added your photo. still, just bring the parts to a plumbing store and in all likely hood they will ID just by sight.

Comment: I think Mike is right.  You can replace the faucets with any brand. They are not attached to the spout.

Comment: thanks Matt, though not what I meant.  What I meant was that the plumbing store will identify the mfr and model for the customer.  They are experts and it will most likely be trivial, and will have the exact oem replacement parts in stock.